# Webpack script execution order

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to convert an existing project to using Webpack. The project code uses a lot of global variables that are tweaked and used in different places. Here is a minimal example of what I'm trying to achieve:

main.js

```
window.foo = {};

import './bar.js';

foo.bar();
```

bar.js

```
foo.bar = function() {
    console.log('bar');
};
```

The entry point is main.js. In my mind, this should declare the global `window.foo`, import `bar.js` for side-effects only, thus adding the `bar` function to `window.foo` and then run it. What actually ends up happening is:

```
bar.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'bar' of undefined
    at eval (bar.js:1)
```

I understand that Webpack may not have been made to handle this type of weird global "modules", but the code base is too big to convert to proper ES6 modules at this moment. For now I'd just like to use Webpack for third party libraries, linting, etc.

How should I make the above example work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let's see what is webpack's output in this situation

```js
// this code in main.js
window.foo = {};

import './bar.js';

foo.bar();


//produces this webpack output

({
  "./src/bar.js": (function(module, exports) {

    foo.bar = function() {
      console.log('bar');
    };

  }),

  "./src/index.js": (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

    "use strict";
    __webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
    /* harmony import */

    /*        ----------Check below line -------------- */


    var _bar_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__("./src/bar.js");



    /* harmony import */
    var _bar_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = /*#__PURE__*/ __webpack_require__.n(_bar_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);
    window.foo = {};
    foo.bar();

  })

});
```

Take a close look where `bar.js` is being imported and actually run.

You can see it's before `window.foo = {}` From my understanding `import` statements are moved to top of the file. I can't tell if this is by the spec or something else, but I know it's also a common eslint rule to have `imports` on top....

Clearly this is not the desired behavior in your case, what you need is a way to have the `imported` code exactly in the place you wrote the `import` statement.

**Now with `require` instead...**

```js
// this code in main.js
window.foo = {};

require('./bar.js');

foo.bar();

// will produce this webpack output

({
  "./src/bar.js": (function(module, exports) {

    foo.bar = function() {
      console.log('bar');
    };

  }),

  "./src/index.js": (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    window.foo = {};

    /* ------------------ Check below line ------------------ */

    __webpack_require__( /*! ./bar.js */ "./src/bar.js");

    foo.bar();

  })

});
```

You can see now that `bar.js` is being `imported` and runs exactly in the place you declared your `require` statement. It seems to me that `require` keeps the original position. Again I can't tell you if this is webpack's stuff or is the actual spec, but anyway in your case it's fine.

*So, to sum up try to `require()` your modules and it should be fine*

Here is a complete article of all the [possible ways to import](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-) stuff with webpack, just in case you find something more intresting

And here is a guide how to [shim globals](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/) with webpack in case you do this somewhere in your app.